# Word Content Control Toolkit

Tags: toolkit

I'm trying to download the Word Content Control Toolkit that used to be at https://dbe.codeplex.com. This link now redirects to the archive https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dbe.

I have downloaded the archive but i see no way of installing the Content Control Toolkit from this archive.

Can someone explain to me on how i use this archive to install the toolkit or any other sites that i can still download the toolkit from?

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb33d060-49a6-407d-a003-6609727b8be8/codeplex-archive-files-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 1):

-> looking on github is the first option you should do... some projects are migrated
-> if not:

1. download & extract the archive
2. go to the release folder
3. inspect the json file > you will see the different versions of the program (check for date reference) > and you will see each filename listed.
4. rename the files acording to the json list.

> run the program.

I was looking for the exact! same thing :) …
I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnqUlpDtWsc